Assumptions of linear regression, when its results are input for a ranking based algorithm
I ran a linear expression with gene expression being the explained variable. Two characteristics of the cell in which it is expressed (the data is single-cell data) are predictors. There are about 300 cells, and I run the regression for each gene separately.
Next, I want to see patterns of change. For this, I use pre-ranked GSEA, which takes a ranked list of genes as input, and calculates for gene-sets a score of their over-representation at the top or bottom of this list. My ranking is sign(log2FC) * -log10(pvalue) for the more interesting predictor of the two.
Question:
Regarding the linearity assumption - should it be checked to hold for all genes? If it doesn't hold, can it bias not only the individual genes estimate, but the rank of their  p-values ?
Note :
If the assumption of homoscedacity is false, then (afaik) the power is low, but the results are not biased (for linear regression of a single gene).
Edited - more details as requested :
One of the predictors is the age of the individual animals from which the cells were derived. There are four different ages, and I have converted the age to be on a continuous scale. I have not looked very precisely at the distribution by age, but it seems the amount of cells per each age is roughly equal. The other predictor is a continuous quality of the cells.
I have a few cell types, the analysis is repeated separately for each one of these, and the numbers vary slightly. Generally, after selecting only for genes that are expressed above zero in about at least 30% of the cells, I have ~3000 genes.
I performed the regressions completely separately. If looking at individual genes, I adjust for multiple comparisons (but it is irrelevant for GSEA).
For one of the cell types I have compared the results of the linear regression with limma (simply lmFit and eBayes on counts which were normalized by Seurat) and the results were almost identical (in terms of the significant genes).

Please edit the question to provide more details. For example, are the predictors continuous, or binary, or multi-level categorical? What were their distributions among the 300 cells? If a predictor was continuous, did you use any transformation of it in the regression? Did you do the regressions completely separately, as the question seems to imply, or did you use tools like those in limma that pool information on error terms among genes? How many genes are you evaluating? Did all cells have detectable levels of expression of all of them?

@EdM Edited the OP

The usual p-values for a linear regression are based on assumptions that the model is correctly specified and that the residual errors are uncorrelated and normally distributed, with zero mean and constant variance. Any violation of those assumptions, in principle, could lead to unreliable p-values (beyond their inherent variability even when the assumptions are met) and thus affect the p-value rankings among genes.
In your situation you might change your model to correct for those potential problems first. With only 4 distinct age values, you can model age as a 4-level unordered categorical predictor to get around any need for a linearity assumption. For the continuous quality predictor, model it flexibly with a regression spline. The limma manual shows how to do that for a continuous time predictor in Section 9.6.2, but the principle applies to any continuous predictor.
I very strongly recommend that you use something like the eBayes moderation of errors provided by limma instead of ranking by the p-values from completely separate regressions. If you rely on the completely separate regressions there's a good chance that your ranking will be more strongly affected by the vagaries of the sampling, with some genes having very small p-values just because their expression values happened just by chance to fit the model better. I also suspect that using moderated errors will lead to less trouble with reviewers.
This page has links and discussion about ways for ranking genes prior to GSEA.
